# How do I get a list of checked items from a custom ListView in Android?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I am experimenting with custom ListView's in Android.  I have subclassed ArrayAdpater to hold an ArrayList of objects.  The objects that get put in the ArrayAdapter come from a SQLite database.
In my ArrayAdapter class, I have overwritten the getView() method and inflate a custom view that puts an ImageView, 3 TextViews, and a Checkbox view on each row of the ListView.

I want to be able to get all the checked rows in my list do something with them, ie. remove them from the list and underlying database or edit the underlying data object represented by that row.

My problem is that I cannot seem to find a way to get my OnItemClickListener to work. The ListView displays fine but nothing happens when I click the row or if I check the checkbox and try to remove the checked items with my removeUnit() method.  I've ran out of ideas.

What am I doing wrong here?  Thanks for any help!

Here is my Activity

```
package com.mack.mylogger;

import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.*;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.util.SparseBooleanArray;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ReportActivity extends Activity {

    private Context context = null;

    DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this); //my database adapter
    ListView reportLV;
    ArrayList<Integer> checkedPositions = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    String TAG = "ReportActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_report);

        // set up the list of finished units
        reportLV = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        reportLV.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

        ArrayList<RUnit> units = new ArrayList<RUnit>(); //init adapter with empty list
        reportLV.setAdapter(new ReportLVAdapter(this, units));
        reportLV.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                Log.d(TAG, "Item is clicked at position: " + position);
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
                cb.toggle();

                if (cb.isChecked()) {
                    checkedPositions.add(position);
                    Log.d(TAG, "Item is checked at position: " + position);
                } else if (!cb.isChecked()) {
                    checkedPositions.remove(position);
                    Log.d(TAG, "Item is unchecked at position: " + position);
                }


            }
        });

        // context
        context = this.getBaseContext();
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        updateListView();

    }

    private void updateListView() {

        // get list of units
        db.read();
        RUnit[] allUnits = db.getAllUnits();
        ArrayList<RUnit> finishedUnits = new ArrayList<RUnit>();
        System.out.println("Units in database: " + allUnits.length);
        RUnit unit;
        for (int i=0; i<allUnits.length; i++) {
            unit = allUnits[i];

                          // check status
            if (unit.getStatus() == "Finished") {
                finishedUnits.add(unit);
            } 

        }
        // update adapter with updated list of finished units
        reportLV.setAdapter(new ReportLVAdapter(this, finishedUnits));
      }

    public void addUnit(View view) {
        // method to run when "Add" button is clicked
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

    public void removeUnit(View view) {
        // method to run when remove button is clicked
        // loop thru the items in the ListView and remove checked items from the db 
        for (int i=0; i<checkedPositions.size(); i++) {
            String unitStr = reportLV.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
            Log.d(TAG, "Removing unit: " + unitStr);

            // remove unit from the database
            db.deleteUnit(unitStr);
        }

        //update the LV
        updateListView();

    }

    public void submit(View view) {
                // do something here
      }


}
```

Here is my ArrayAdapter

```
package com.mack.mylogger;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.*;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import java.util.*;

public class ReportLVAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RUnit> {

    private final Activity context;
    private final ArrayList<RUnit> units;

    String TAG = new String("ReportLVAdapter");

    static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView serial;
        public TextView status;
        public TextView date;
        public ImageView model;
        public ImageView flag;
        public CheckBox checkbox;
    }


    public ReportLVAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<RUnit> units) {
        super(context, R.layout.adapterlv_report, units);
        this.context = context;
        this.units = units;

        Log.d(TAG, "Size of adapter array: " + units.size());
      }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View rowView = convertView;
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        if (rowView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapterlv_report, null);
            viewHolder.serial = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.serial);
            viewHolder.model = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.model);
            viewHolder.status = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.status);
            viewHolder.date = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.date);
            viewHolder.flag = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.flag);
            viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) rowView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
            rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
                } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        }

        // Need to handle empty database situation
        // get info from RUnit obj
        RUnit unit = units.get(position);
        String sn = unit.getSerialNumAsString();
        String mdl = unit.getModel();
        String stat = unit.getStatus();

        // date
        String d;
        if (stat == "Finished") { d = unit.getFinishDate(); }
        else if (stat == "Submitted") { d = unit.getSubmitDate(); }
        else if (stat == "Shipped") { d = unit.getShipDate(); }
        else { d = "NA"; }

        // flags
        String[] flags = unit.getFlags();

        ///// Set view values

        // text values
        viewHolder.serial.setText(sn);
        viewHolder.status.setText(stat);
        viewHolder.date.setText(d);

        // set model image
        if (mdl == "TK") {
            viewHolder.model.setImageResource(R.drawable.tk_icon);
        } else {
            // must be carrier
            viewHolder.model.setImageResource(R.drawable.carrier_icon);
        }

        // set flag image - only look for hold
        for (int i=0; i<flags.length; i++) {
            if (flags[i] == "hold") {
                // set hold image
                viewHolder.flag.setImageResource(R.drawable.hold_flag);
            } else {
                // no image
            }
        }

        return rowView;
    }
```

My activity XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/main_title"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subtitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/title"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/report_subtitle"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_submit"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/button_submit"
        android:onClick="submit"
        android:textSize="26sp" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/button_group"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/button_submit"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal" > 

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:onClick="addUnit"
            android:text="@string/button_add_fg" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:text="@string/button_modify_fg" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:onClick="removeUnit"
            android:text="@string/button_remove_fg" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/button_group"
        android:layout_below="@id/subtitle"
        android:footerDividersEnabled="true"
        android:headerDividersEnabled="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My custom View for the rows XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<GridLayout
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:columnCount="5"
    android:rowCount="2"   
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/model"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> 

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/serial"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:textSize="35dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/status"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/flag"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:layout_rowSpan="2"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> 

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="4"
        android:layout_rowSpan="2"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> 

</GridLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post your XML?
Did you add `android:descendantFocusable="blockDescendants"` to your ListView?

Answer (score 0):

You can call getCheckedItemPositions() on the list view.  This will return a SparseBooleanArray containing ALL items in the list and whether or not they are checked.  Once you have that, you can loop through the array and use valueAt(i) to determine if an item is selected or not.

[Here's a good article on this topic](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-multiple-selection-listview/).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
SparseBooleanArray checkedPositions = lv.getCheckedItemPositions ();int size = checkedPositions.size ();for (int i=0 ; i<size ; i++) {
 // We get the key stored at the index 'i'
 int key = checkedPositions.keyAt (i);
 // We get the boolean value with the key
 Log.i (Tag, "checkedPositions(" + key + ")=" + checkedPositions.get (key));}
```

Comment: I have tried getCheckedItemPositions(), however, I always get an array with all false values (no items checked).  It seems that here is no connection between my custom checkbox and what the listview knows is checked.

Comment: I have also tried adding a OnClickListener to the View when it is created in the getView() method of the adapter.  This allowed me to toggle the checkbox when the item was clicked.  However I still could not get a list of the checked items.